# Bundle.toString() is not working in onActivityResult()

Tags: java, android, bundle

i have two activities , one is **MainActivity** and second is **SecondActivity**

I started **SecondActivity** like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();   
bundle.putString("username","User");
bundle.putString("password", "pwd");
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then in **SecondActivity** i am printing `Bundle` String representation

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
Log.i("MyTag2",bundle.toString()); // output is Bundle[{username=User, password=pwd}]
```

And it's working fine but when i am logging `Bundle.toString()` in **MainActivity** within **onActivityResult()** then its printing `Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=80]`
here is code from **onActivityResult()**

```
Log.i("TAG",data.getExtras().toString()); // but here output is Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=80] why ?
// data is Intent object received
```

Edit : `Bundle.toString()` is working fine means its giving me `Bundle[{username=User, password=pwd}]` but only in `SecondActivity`

Comment: What are you expecting it to print? and why?

Comment: data.getExtras() returns a bundle. Use data.getExtras().getString("username") to get the values.

Comment: @user207421 See my edit , you will get what i am expecting

Comment: But why are you expecting that? The Javadoc for `Bundle.toString()` doesn't say anything about it one way or the other: it is in fact just inherited from the Javadoc for `java.lang.Object.toString()`. Clearly in the second piece of code the `Bundle` is still parcelled up.

Comment: You shouldn't be logging usernames and passwords anyway ...

Comment: @user207421 i am logging username and password its just a example but why both output are different when bundle is same on both situation

Comment: It isn't the same, obviously, it is still parcelled in the second case. The Javadoc gives you no reason to rely on either of these two formats.

Answer (score 1):

Bundle is not something you can simply `toString()` and view the contents. Bundles can contain *any data*. Think about it - would you be able to simply `toString()` an entire array and view the contents as String? No, you would first need to extract the elements from the array, and only **if** they are able to be represented in a String format and have an associated `toString()` method, you will be able to call the method and get it to work properly.

Essentially, extract the contents from the Bundle and `toString()` them individually.

Even if you could do this on a Bundle, I'd still recommend against it, since if you added a different type of data in your Bundle in future iterations of your application, it might cause the program to crash or behave unexpectedly if the data format is not properly supported a certain way.